# Prove: If points of a convergent sequence are reordered, the new sequence converges to the same limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

I am having trouble wrapping my mind around this proof I found online.

Let $p_n$, $n ∈ \Bbb N$ be a sequence in a metric space $(E, d)$. Suppose $lim_{n→∞} p_n = p ∈ E$. Let $f : N → N$ be a bijection. Let $q_m = p_{f(m)}$
. Hence, the sequence $q_m$ is a
reordering of the points of $p_n$.
Let $ \epsilon > 0$. Since $p_n$ converges, there exists $N ∈ \Bbb N$ such that $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon $ for all $n > N$.
Let $M = max\{N ∪ \{f(n)\  |\ 0 ≤ n ≤ N\}\}$. Let $m > M$. Suppose $d(q_m, p) ≥ \epsilon$. Then for $n = f^{
−1}
(m)$, we have $d(p_n, p) ≥ \epsilon$. This implies that $0 ≤ n ≤ N$ which contradicts
the choice of $m > M$. Hence $d(q_m, p) < \epsilon$. Thus, $q_m$ also converges to $p = lim_{n→∞} p_n$.

First I am having trouble understanding the choice of $M$ and why this ensures that $p_m$ will be in the neighborhood of $p$. Next, I am confused how that is a contradiction. This probably stems from my confusion about $M$, but mainly I do not understand why that implies $0 \le n \le N$.

Comment: It seems to me like a simpler choice for $M$ would be $M=max\{f^{-1}(n):1 \leq n \leq N\}$.  Then $m>M$ $\implies f(m)>N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $q_m=p_n$. So $d(q_m,p)=d(p_n)\ge\epsilon$. If $n>N$,  then $d(p_n,p)<\epsilon$ by the choice of $N$. Therefore, $0\le n\le N$, but $m=f(n)>f(k)$ for all k such that $0\le k\le N$. This contradicts the fact that $M$ is the maximum of such numbers.

I'm thinking that $M$ should be $\max\{f(n):0\le n\le N\}$, instead of $\max\{N\cup\{f(n):0\le n\le N\}\}$.